# VBA/object required for Find. function unable

Tags: excel, vba

I kept getting the error: object variable or with block variable not set

context: I'm trying to find the data across two workbooks with two worksheet. basically the need is to Find data from column B in workbook 2, find these data across column Q,S,AV in workbook 1 and return found values in column AQ in workbook 1

Usually the code works fine if it's performend within the same workbook same sheet, but now as I splitted them apart, i kept getting the mentioned error. I figure the problem might lay in how I declare the incorrect <object> but still haven't been able to solved this. I'm fairly new to VBA as well.

```
Sub FindDuplicate()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Long: x = 2
Dim searchvalue As Variant
Dim searchrange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim lastrowQ As Long
Dim lastrowS As Long
Dim lastrowAV As Long

'initialize variables'

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rawdata") 
lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column B from workbook2'
lastrowQ = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row 'last row in Q,S,AV'
lastrowS = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowAV = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "AV").End(xlUp).Row


'loop through the value in column B from worksheet 2'
For i = 1 To lastrow
    searchvalue = ws2.Cells(i, "B").Value 'get value in col B'
    Set searchrange = ws1.Range("Q2:S631,AV2:AV631") 'search range for rawdata'
Set foundCell = searchrange.Find(searchvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    ws1.Cells(x, "AQ").Value = foundCell
    x = x + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I expect the code to loop through the data in workbook 2 find those data in three separate columns in workbook 1 and return in column AQ in workbook 1.

Comment: `ws2` is not set

Comment: didn't I already declare ws2 as Worksheet in the first line?  or is it that I need to declare workbook separatedly for each worksheet as well? Thanks.

Comment: You've set ws1 `Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rawdata")` but not ws2 `Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lessrawdata")` (or something similar)

Comment: I see so do I have to declare a separate workbook (e.g., Dim Wb2 as Workbook) for this ? Thanks :)_

Comment: If you're working with the two worksheets in the same workbook, then no. If they're in separate workbooks, then yes. See it as pages in a book.

Comment: You could skip the declaring part for the second workbook (`Dim Wb2`). Instead you set your worksheet object `ws2` like this: `Set ws2 = Workbooks("theOtherWorkbookName").Worksheets("lessrawdata")`